# Setting a testing a cookie with Javascript issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

So at the moment I am working on setting a cookie in the user's browser... this is how I have done so:

```
    var cookiename = "benjaminpotter_welcome";
    var cookievalue = "visited";
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+604800000)
    var cookieExpiration = date.toGMTString();
    var cookiepath = "; path=/";
    var myCookie = cookiename + "=" + cookievalue + ";expires=" + cookieExpiration + path;
    document.cookie = myCookie;
```

And this is how I have attempted to receive it:

```
    function readCookie(benjaminpotter_welcome) {
     cookieName = cookieName.replace(/([.\\+\-*:\/?!|^${}()\[\]])/g, '\\$1');
     var re = new RegExp('[; ]'+cookieName+'=([^\\s;]*)');
     var sMatch = (' '+document.cookie).match(re);
     if (cookieName && sMatch){ 
     var cookieval = unescape(sMatch[1]);
     }else{
     var cookieval = '';
     };
    };
```

The thing is that it isn't working at all...

Here is what I want to happen... I want to set a cookie in the user's browser called 'benjaminpotter_welcome' having the value 'visited'.

Then I need to request that cookie (on the next page load of course) and test to see whether it = 'visited', upon which code will be executed (or in my case not executed.

Here is the part of my website that is not working currently when attempting to use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function readCookie(benjaminpotter_welcome) {
         cookieName = cookieName.replace(/([.\\+\-*:\/?!|^${}()\[\]])/g, '\\$1');
         var re = new RegExp('[; ]'+cookieName+'=([^\\s;]*)');
         var sMatch = (' '+document.cookie).match(re);
         if (cookieName && sMatch){ 
         var cookieval = unescape(sMatch[1]);
         }else{
         var cookieval = '';
         };
        };

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#thanks").fadeOut(0);
    $("#overlay_big").fadeOut(0);
    readCookie();
    if(cookieval == 'visited'){
    }else{
        $("#overlay_big").delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: One point; you `+ path` when perhaps you mean `+ cookiepath` ?

Comment: If you aren't doing this as an exercise for learning cookies, your efforts will be simplified by giving a look at the jQuery Cookie plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `cookieval` inside the method, which makes it a private variable. Try:

```
function readCookie(cookieName) {
    cookieName = cookieName.replace(/([.\\+\-*:\/?!|^${}()\[\]])/g, '\\$1');
    var re = new RegExp('[; ]'+cookieName+'=([^\\s;]*)');
    var sMatch = (' '+document.cookie).match(re);

    return cookieName && sMatch ? unescape(sMatch[1]) : '';
};
```

and your DOM-ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#thanks").fadeOut(0);
    $("#overlay_big").fadeOut(0);
    var cookieval = readCookie("benjaminpotter_welcome");
    if(!cookieval == 'visited'){
        $("#overlay_big").delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
    };
});
```

should do it.

If you understood your code, I can recommend the [jquery.cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to work with cookies with javascript.

Comment: I love the jQuery way - simple as!